# jqgrid custom tooltip for cell validation and dynamic error row indicator

Tags: validation, jqgrid, tooltip, cell

[image]

The jqgrid cells with errors should be highlighted in red, when hovered over it a custom tooltip should be shown. Also a column should be added with error icon in that row. Is this possible in jqgrid. I am new at it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the version of jqgrid plugin you are using?

Comment: @Vim: We are using 4.5.4